# why required not working while uploading image with cropper js in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, cropperjs

Hello guys i am building a project where i have used cropper js to crop the uploaded image everything is working fine with my codes like file is getting cropped getting uploaded to database as well but the problem is while i want to check that the file field should not be empty i am using the required but its not working i am pasting the codes that i have used till now can you guys please see what do i need to do to rectify the errors please.

HTML

```
<form id="partyins"  class="needs-validation" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

                          
 <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:5%;">
   <input type="file" id="image" class="form-control" required>

  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){ echo $_GET['product_id']; } ?>">
                          

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-upload-image mt-4" style="margin-top:2%">Upload Image</button>
  </div>
                             
</form>
```

JS PART

```
var resize = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    enableOrientation: true,    
    viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
        width: 64,
        height: 64,
        type: 'circle' //square
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});


$('#image').on('change', function () { 
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      resize.croppie('bind',{
        url: e.target.result
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});


$("#partyins").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var prod_id = $('#product_id').val();

  resize.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (img) {

    if(img == ''){
      toastr.error("Please upload a file",'Error');
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "model/product_image/product_image.php?insertimg&imgid="+prod_id,
      type: "POST",
      data: {"image":img},
      success: function (data) {
       var res = data;
         if(res==8){
            toastr.error("Sorry! There is an error",'Error');
          }else if(res==9){
            toastr.error("Please upload a file",'Error');
          }else{
           toastr.success(data,'Update');
           $('#partyins')[0].reset();

         }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['insertimg']) && isset($_GET['imgid'])){

  $id = $_GET['imgid'];

  $image = $_POST['image'];

  list($type, $image) = explode(';',$image);
  list(, $image) = explode(',',$image);

  $image = base64_decode($image);
  $image_name = 'product_id'.$id.'_'.time().'.png';
  file_put_contents("../../../upload_products/".$image_name, $image);

  if(!$image == ''){

    $sql_inst = "UPDATE $tb_products SET `p_upload`='$image_name' WHERE id='$id'";
    $res_inst = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_inst);   
    if($res_inst){
      echo "Updated Successfully";

    }else{
      echo 8;
    } 

  }else{

    echo 9;

  }

  


}
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: @Wesley Smith actually the file is getting uploaded blank what do i want is that if file is not provided it should not get uploaded

Comment: @Dharman yes i know that

Comment: Check the input **before** calling `resize.croppie('result'...` and react accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl according to you it showing the toastr error 'Please upload a file' but then alos getting uploaded.

Comment: I mean don't proceed to the `result` promise if there is no file

Comment: Then put the ajax in an `else` statement. Your `if()` doesn't stop the upload by itself

Comment: Yes @charlietfl i found one answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way I hope it may work

```
var image = $('#image').val();

  if(image == ''){
      toastr.error("Please upload a file",'Error');
    }else{

      resize.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (img) {


      $.ajax({
        url: "model/product_image/product_image.php?insertimg&imgid="+prod_id,
        type: "POST",
        data: {"image":img},
        success: function (data) {
         var res = data;
           if(res==8){
              toastr.error("Sorry! There is an error",'Error');
            }else if(res==9){
              toastr.error("Please upload a file",'Error');
            }else{
             toastr.success(data,'Update');
             $('#partyins')[0].reset();

           }
        }
      });
    });

    }
```